# How to set number of columns with a specific absolute size in a table layout panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I need to set number of columns in a table layout panel with a specific size. The size of the user controls is locked. When I maximize the form I want to change the number of columns in a row.

How can I do that with the getting the new width of table layout panel and setting the number of columns?

With this case I can change the number of user controls in a row.

Answer (score 1):

To set the number of Columns when resized -

`tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = tableLayoutPanel1.Width / 100;`

And set the column size style -

`tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[ColIndex].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[ColIndex].Width = *DesiredWidth*;`

Note that if there are 6 columns and then you resize it such that only 3 columns will be present then the controls placed in those columns will be lost.

[MSDN - TableLayoutPanel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2t82c7dk.aspx)